# How to count number of cells whose contents start with 0?

Tags: excel, count, excel-formula, worksheet-function, zero

I need to count how many cells are in a column, but all the content of the cells are `id numbers` that start with `0`.  For example, a column of numbers say A1-A3 looks like:

```
0253980
0253980  
0250137
```

The answer should be "3" but `=COUNT(A1:A3)` produces "0".  This is because the `id numbers` commence `0`.  I do not want to convert the numbers because they will be part of other queries later where people need to copy and paste thousands of `id numbers` into a program which will not work if the `0` is removed.

Is is possible to do a count on these cells?

Answer (score 0):

In Excel what look like numbers are text strings when they start `0` (in general, though numbers may be displayed as preceded with one or more zeros through formatting - all credit to @chris neilsen for reminding me of that!), since Excel automatically strips leading zeros from numeric values. [=COUNT](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/count-function-HP010342338.aspx):

> counts the number of cells that contain numbers, and counts numbers within the list of arguments. Use the COUNT function to get the number of entries in a number field that is in a range or array of numbers.

so is not suitable for text strings. However [=COUNTA](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/counta-HP005209027.aspx):

> Counts the number of cells that are not empty and the values within the list of arguments. Use COUNTA to count the number of cells that contain data in a range or array.

Hence fortunately the solution is very simply to substitute one function for the other and :

```
=COUNTA(A1:A3)
```

Comment: _In Excel what look like numbers are text strings when they start 0_ true, unless the cell has a number format that produces a leading `0` (`0000000` would do it in this case)